# Is there a way to set window.onbeforeunload to null before an object is click?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am using wtforms and here is my submit button:

```
{{ form.submit(class="btn btn-outline-info") }}
```

And This is my onbeforeunload function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  window.onbeforeunload = function() {
  return "Are you sure you want to navigate away?";
  }
</script>
```

I know in normal html forms I can probably use jquery to do this:

reference:

[jquery-function-before-form-submission stackoverflow discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21938788/jquery-function-before-form-submission/40330287)

[clear onbeforunload stackoverflow discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14093826/clear-onbeforeunload?)

```
<head>
  <script src="jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<script>
$('#myform').submit(function(event) {

 event.preventDefault(); //this will prevent the default submit

  window.onbeforeunload = null;
  
 $(this).unbind('submit').submit(); // continue the submit unbind preventDefault
})
<script>
```

What should I do when I am working with these wtforms object? (p.s. I am not familiar with js or jquery....please point out what I done wrong if any....)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I doubt you need to call `preventDefault()`. if you plan to submit any way. I'd just set `onbeforeunload` to null and return true (returning true lets the submit continue).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option is to use `addEventListener` instead of `onbeforeunload`

```js
const myFunc = function() {
  return "Are you sure you want to navigate away?";
}
window.addEventListener('beforeunload', myFunc);
```

and then on the `submit` method, remove the listener

```js
window.removeEventListener('beforeunload', myFunc);
```

Answer (score 0):

So this is probably not the best way to do it! But it's a really good work-around! since  wtforms object does not allowed passing any additional function i.e. onclick or whatsoever information into the {} curly bracket a work-around is to wrapped it! so the main thing about adding all those thing is to call a function to disable the onbeforeunload and thus a quick solution will be

onbeforeunload function(stay the same):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  window.onbeforeunload = function() {
  return "Are you sure you want to navigate away?";
  }
</script>
```

disable onbeforeunload function:

```
<script>
  function submit()
  {
    window.onbeforeunload = null;
  }
</script>
```

and for submit button:

```
<a onclick="submit()">{{ form.submit(class="btn btn-outline-info") }}</a>
```

Couldn't imagine this took me so long to figured it out, btw thanks @terrymorse who made me figured out how easy the question actually is! Thanks to all who comments and provide solution and edit my questions!